# Reverse Engineering a Bell Curve

Tags: r

I simulated numbers from a Normal Distribution centered around 50 and then kept numbers only between 0 and 100:

```
mean <- 50
sd <- 15
n <- 100000

set.seed(123)  
numbers <- rnorm(n, mean, sd)

numbers <- pmax(0, pmin(numbers, 100))
```

As expected, the results look like a bell curve:

[image]

Then, I wanted to see what percentage of numbers are between each unit interval:

```
min_interval <- seq(0, 99, by = 1)
max_interval <- seq(1, 100, by = 1)


count <- sapply(min_interval, function(x) {
    sum(numbers >= x & numbers < (x + 1))
})
percentage <- count / length(numbers) * 100

df <- data.frame(min_interval = min_interval,
                 max_interval = max_interval,
                 count = count,
                 percentage = percentage)
```

The results look something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(desc(percentage))

    min_interval max_interval count percentage
1             50           51  2714      2.714
2             48           49  2632      2.632
3             49           50  2628      2.628
4             52           53  2626      2.626
5             47           48  2615      2.615

#> sum(df$percentage)
#[1] 99.957
```

**My Question:** Suppose I wanted to make the following changes to this results table (df) such that:

- (min_interval = 50, max_interval = 51) has a percentage of 5%
- (min_interval = 49, max_interval = 50) has a percentage of 5%
- The percentage columns still sums to 1
- The plot still keeps its approximate shape

**How can I re-calculate the percentage column such that these conditions are met? Can a general function be written for this problem? (e.g. enter which constraints you want, and an optimization algorithm finds the corresponding bell curve)**

**Related Question**

- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4804927/calculating-the-probabilities-of-a-100-sided-weighted-dice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's great that you're using simulations to learn statistics, that's an enjoyable way to learn.

the function `pnorm` tells you the proportion of a normal distribution (also sometimes called a "bell curve") that is below a certain value. You can find the proportion of a normal distribution that will be between two points by differencing their value in `pnorm`. For example, with your parameters, the expected proportion between 49 and 50 is

```
pnorm(50,mean=50, sd=15) - pnorm(49, mean=50, sd=15)
# 0.02657646
```

or about 2.657%, no so far off your simulated 2.628%.

To find a normal distribution with 5% in this range, you can make a function that is the proportion in a range

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  pnorm(50,mean=50,sd=x) - pnorm(49, mean=50, sd=x)
}
plot(x <- seq(0,10,len=100),f1(x), type="l")
# horizontal line at 0.05, or 5%
abline(0.05,0)
```

so you can no pick off the plot where this property holds.

If you want to solve for that, use `optimize` to find the spot where this crossing happens. The crossing is when `f1(x) - 0.05` is zero, so define `f2` as

```
f2 <- function(x) {
  abs(f1(x) - 0.05)
}
```

The absolute value allows us to minimize the function at the unique solution

```
optimize(lower=5,upper=10,f=f2)
# $minimum
# [1] 7.957901
# 
# $objective
# [1] 3.038535e-08
```

this shows that if you set the standard deviation to 7.956, you should get about 5% of the distribution between 49 and 50.

Comment: @ pdb: thank you so much for your answer!  I became curious about this problem lately  ... do you think the approach you suggested is applicable to these types of problems here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4804927/calculating-the-probabilities-of-a-100-sided-weighted-dice  , i.e. add more constraints ?

Comment: earlier, I tried to solve a similar type of problem using a linear programming style approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77464036/solving-recursive-math-problems-in-r-python